# Accessing info from database asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, user-accounts, user-management

I have added as below to get some more user info, and updated the database, it all works as it should, however im trying to add in the index view of manage folder so that the FullName, birthdate and Country will show, but i cant really get it working... can someone point me in the right direction?

AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, FullName = model.FullName, Country = model.Country, BirthDate = model.BirthDate };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

accountviewmodel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

IdentityModels:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div>
<h4>Change your account settings</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Full Name:</dt>
    <dd></dd>

    <dt>Birth Date:</dt>
    <dd></dd>

    <dt>Country:</dt>
    <dd>
        Comming soon
    </dd>


    <dt>Password:</dt>
    <dd>
        [
        @if (Model.HasPassword)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Change your password", "ChangePassword")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Create", "SetPassword")
        }
        ]
        </dd>
```

AccountViewModels:

```
public class SetNameViewModel
{
    [Display(Name ="Set Name")]
    public string SetName { get; set; }
}

public class SetCountryViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Set Country")]
    public string SetCountry { get; set; }
}
```

ManageController:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetTwoFactorSuccess ? "Your two-factor authentication provider has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : message == ManageMessageId.AddPhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was added."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemovePhoneSuccess ? "Your phone number was removed."
            : "";

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
         //ADDED THEESE LINES
     var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
           var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
      ////
        var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            HasPassword = HasPassword(),
            PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
            TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
            Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
            BrowserRemembered = await        AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId),

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now if i use:

```
    @User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

in my view i get the user id, but how do i fetch fullname etc?

```
  @User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

returns me the username of the id aswell

added

```
         ViewBag.CurrentUser = currentUser;
```

to my managecontroller and now i can get the things i want in view with @Viewbag.CurrentUser.Country, BirthDate and Fullname! yay me, now i want to give the users the option to edit their info... that will be a harder cookie to crumble i guess!

Comment: Where is the Index.cshtml view under manage? Did you update that to display the new properties? Can you post it's content?

Comment: @Jack edited post, as you can see i havent gotten far on this...

Comment: OK, you have an index view. So set it's model to your RegisterViewModel and plug in the @model.FullName etc in your view. Now you should have a corresponding Index action in your controller where you populate that viewmodel and display the view. Not sure what your trying to accomplish with the code at the bottom.

Comment: @SteveGreene i guess that would work, however i alrdy got the model set SampleProject.Models.IndexViewModel so i need to edit my indexviewmodel  i guess, since it holds all other info

Comment: tried with         public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; } in the indexviewmodel but i get nothing back, if i set to bool i get FALSE on all if that helps

Comment: @SteveGreene Im just trying to give the users options to View their name birthdate and country they set when they registered on the mvc site

Comment: What does your Index action look like? That's where you should be filling whatever view model your using and then pass it to your Index view. So go grab your custom information with a command like "context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);" and then move that into your viewmodel.

Comment: @SteveGreene i have updated the post with idex action of ManageController i kinda get what youre saying but i cant really find any good practise on how to do it, kinda new to asp and c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding ViewBag.CurrentUser = currentUser; to the ManageController worked out for me!